# Sort, sum and save in csv format

Tags: r

I have a csv file that contains a data; TYPE and Area. I want to sort the data based on type and then add the area, after that i want to save that file in a csv/excel format.
The data looks like as follows;

```
TYPE    Area
P   38304
P   14729
P   39342
R   652
R   497
C   4506
U   1705
U   1513
U   1514
U   1531
U   1580
U   1581
U   113509
U   13198
U   114730
U   12402
C   3252
```

I want to make the data as follows

```
P   R   U   C
38304   652 1705    4506
14729   497 1513    3252
39342       1514    
            1531    
            1580    
            1581    
            113509  
            13198   
            114730  
            12402
```

And then Do the sum by column

```
P   R   U   C
92375   1149    263263  7758
```

so far i have following codes;

```
  data=read.table("Book1.csv", header=TRUE, sep=',')
    x=(sapply(split(data$Area, data$TYPE), sort))
    write.csv(x, file="test.csv")
```

I tried to do the write csv first but due to unequal row i cannot write the csv. I am stuck, i know it is possible to add first and then write the final output but i am not able to do the coding. 
Thanks Lira

Comment: Are we talking `xtabs(Area ~ TYPE, data)`?

Comment: Or `tapply(df$Area,df$TYPE,sum)`. If you want to split the values in `Area` according to `TYPE`: `split(df$Area,df$TYPE)` (and then `sapply(split(df$Area,df$TYPE),sum)`).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works !

```
library(plyr)
newdata <- data[order(Type, Area),] 
data.new <- ddply(newdata, c("TYPE"), summarise, Area = sum("Area")) 
t.data   <- t(data.new)
write.csv(x, file="test.csv")
```